# Why was the ramchal banned, and how did he become so widely accepted later?

Tags: history, ramchal, cherem

When ramchal was in Italy he was put in cherem for his writing and eventually left to live in Israel. Why did this happen and what changed about the perception of him?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/63746/759

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22744/759

Comment: Similar but not a duplicate. This question asks about the author while that one asks about a specific work of the author

Comment: My unresearched opinion is that the universal ban against him by European Jewry was never revoked. It was only in the next century, in the late 19th century, once the controversy over his kabbalistic "revelations", died down (and he ceased to be a threatening charismatic strange young man, as he was long dead), that his work Messilat Yesharim became popularized by the _baalei Mussar_. The next century, the 20th century saw the revival of his other writings due to the popularity of the Messialt Yesharim. This continued with the publication of his various works through the last few decades.

Answer (score 2):

The Ramchal was born 31 years after the death of [Shabbtai Zvi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatai_Zevi), a false Messiah, who turned many Jews away from religion. As such the rabbanim in Italy, who misunderstood some of the Ramchal's writings for messianic, were very afraid of "another Shabbtai Zvi story" and [threatened him with excommunication](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/63754/11501) unless he stopped writing.

The Ramchal agreed to stop writing on kabbala and left Italy for Amsterdam in 1734 hoping the more liberal environment there would help him write more freely (that is where [he wrote Mesilat Yesharim for instance](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68058/which-books-of-the-ramchal-did-he-publish-himself/68197#68197)). He finally made alyah during the last years of his life.

The second part of your question on the changing perception has been answered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22754/11501) in a wonderful way.

For sources and more see his [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Chaim_Luzzatto) and R Yirmeyahu Bindman's [biography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568212933) of the Ramchal.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Messianic-Mysticism-Moses-Luzzatto-School/dp/1874774099

Comment: Ch. 7-8 https://books.google.com/books?id=N7PQjAl8ugMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false